# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express error: Cannot open database "PersonnelPro" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config, database-connection, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and the "SQL Server and Windows Authentication" mode in my database. I can open the database using Enterprise Manager, but when I run my aspx application, I get:

> *Cannot open database "PersonnelPro" requested by the login. The login
>   failed.*

My web.config connection string is:

```
<add name="dbString" 
     connectionString="Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=AREA51\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PersonnelPro;User Id= ****;Password= ****" />`
```

I searched the web and SO, but could not find a solution. Any ideas what would be causing this issue?

**Update:**
Looking into SQL log files ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log"), I find this:

```
2012-12-21 05:58:00.97 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2012-12-21 05:58:00.97 Logon       Login failed for user 'PersonnelPro'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <named pipe>]
```

This web application is by a 3rd party company. So technically, I only need to configure my web.config file and it should work.

Comment: First places I would start would be to remove `Provider=sqloledb;` and check your username and password.

Comment: Provider=sqloledb is provided by the application vendor (they went out of business). Username and password have been verified (since I have copied the uid & pwd from the web.config file, pasted it to Enterprise Manager, and it works).

Comment: @JefferyKhan when I remove "Provider=sqloledb" I get an error that reads: An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString. An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'.

Comment: Maybe stating something you have tried but - have you enabled TCP/IP connections? This has bitten some people in the past - even if the protocol is installed it may not be enabled - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191294.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space after the '=' sign for User Id and Password. I think it is being interpreted as part of the value.

**Update:**

The new error message you posted (Failed to open the explicitly specified database.) can mean one of two things:

- The DB with that name doesn't exist or is misspelled.
- The user you are trying to log in with does not have access to the DB. You can check this by running `exec sp_helpuser 'username'` in the DB.

Comment: I removed the space, but still getting the same error message.